# Accept only 0 and 1 in input field

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I want to accept only **0** and **1** in input field **and** add spaces after every 4 digits.
With the following I can add spaces but it accepts all digits. How can I restrict it to only 0 and 1 instead of all digits? I'm having difficulty in the pattern.

```
document.getElementById('num').addEventListener('input', function (e) {
  e.target.value = e.target.value.replace(/[^\d]/g, '').replace(/(.{4})/g, '$1 ').trim();
});
```

**Demo:**
https://jsfiddle.net/5rvfgpzo/

Comment: you can use masking regex

Comment: Sam, do you also expect a fixed number of groups of 4? Or is "1010 01" also valid input?

Comment: in your input field you can say type number min=0 max=1 step=1 then it allows only zero and one

Comment: @Alex, then you cannot enforce the spaces.

Comment: You just have to replace `.replace(/[^\d]/g, '')` with `.replace(/[^0-1]/g, '')`

Comment: `<input type="number" id="quantity" name="quantity" min="0" max="1">` - This is enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You can try this :**

```js
document.getElementById('num').addEventListener('input', function (e) {

  e.target.value = e.target.value.replace(/[^0-1]/g, '').replace(/(.{4})/g, '$1 ').trim();
});
```

```css
input {
  width: 200px;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<label for="num">num</label>
<input id="num" type="text" min="0" max="1" name="num" maxlength="14" />
```